# Sign Key HMAC SHA1 with Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, utf-8, base64, cryptojs

For some reason I am not able to create a signature from a private key in JS. Using this online help from google:

https://m4b-url-signer.appspot.com/

URL:https://google.maps.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=New+York&client=test

Example Key (fake for the purposes of the exercise)
Key: QNade5DtdJKKZbidTsrIgONupc4=

(Result) Signature: XDsiH5JAY7kJLgA1K2PWlhTdO1k=

However, my javascript code:

```
var keyString = 'QNade5DtdJKKZbidTsrIgONupc4=';
    console.log(keyString)

var urlString = encodeURIComponent('/maps/api/geocode/json?address=New+York&client=test');
console.log(urlString)

// We need to decode private key to binary
var decoded_key_words = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(keyString);
var decoded_key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(decoded_key_words);

console.log(decoded_key);

var signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(decoded_key,urlString);
console.log(signature);

//  Encode binary signature to base 64
var encoded_signature = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(signature);
console.log(encoded_signature)
```

Gives me a signature:

bOenVNeXI6xI1xlSa77oqGKssyY=

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Am I decoding base64 incorrectly?

Comment: I would like to point out that this is confidential information, not supposed to be posted on a public forum such as StackOverflow. You should contact Google for Work support. Here's a link: https://support.google.com/work/answer/142244?hl=en

Comment: @KayAnn Hi Kay, many thanks for your reply but why is this confidential? The numbers in my post are all made up (it's not the real key) and google has plenty of documentation online about python signing keys, just not js. For example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices/auth I just want to know how to decode from base64 to binary in JS as I think I am missing that step.

Comment: You should mention that in your question that is made up. Also, keys, signature and client secret are in general sensitive information because they are app specific and can be a cause for security hindrance. Well, I would still encourage you to ask this question in the support forum, chances are you will get the accurate explanation and/or solution.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, this worked:

```
<script src="sha.js"></script>

var url = '/maps/api/geocode/json?address=New+York&client=test';
var key = 'QNade5DtdJKKZbidTsrIgONupc4='

var hmacObj = new jsSHA(url, 'TEXT');
var hmacOutput = hmacObj.getHMAC(key,'B64','SHA-1','B64');

console.log(hmacOutput)
```

Giving me:

XDsiH5JAY7kJLgA1K2PWlhTdO1k=