# Google Web Services HMAC-SHA1 algorithm in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, sha, hmac, hmacsha1

I am trying to get a `HMAC-SHA1` encryption going using JavaScript so I can use it in my `Google Web Services For Work` `GET` requests. I've tried several libraries and solutions, such as the following example:

[Sign Key HMAC SHA1 with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30379084/sign-key-hmac-sha1-with-javascript)

and this other one:

https://gist.github.com/ncerminara/11257943#file-base64-js

as well as CryptoJS, but all of them give me different results, which none of them work. I was wondering if someone got this to work. I am aware of the python example posted here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices/auth, which does work but unfortunately I need to achieve the same functionality in `JavaScript` to upload it to `Cloud Code` in `Parse`.

I would greatly appreciate any advice regarding this matter.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Cheers!

Comment: Hey, i have the same problem, you  know how solved it now? thx!